# EADDRNOTAVAIL when binding 127.0.0.1 on localhost?

Tags: macos, sockets, darwin

I'm getting `errno==49 (EADDRNOTAVAIL)` when trying to UDP-`bind()` to 127.0.0.1:47346 running Mac OS X on a G5 (big endian PowerPC). Is there something preventing me from doing so? I've tried other addresses and ports (192.168.1.2 and port 47346) but with no success.

Here's a gdb printout of my sockaddr_in:

```
$1 = {
  sin_len = 0 '\0', 
  sin_family = 2 '\002', 
  sin_port = 47346, 
  sin_addr = {
    s_addr = 3232235778
  }, 
  sin_zero = "???\000\000??"
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should fill the sin_len field as well (with sizeof(struct sockaddr_in), that should do the trick). This field is not appearing on each platform, but on which it exists, it must be filled.

Futhermore, be sure to bzero the structure before using it (but it clearly seems you did it anyway).

Comment: That worked for me as well! Empirically, you need to bzero the structure or `bind` will still fail.

Comment: Setting the length had no effect, zeroing the structure worked for me.  In my case this was 3rd party code and I overlooked this completely.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a good way to determine (via #defines) if `sin_len` should be filled in? I'm using `__APPLE__` but I'm not sure that's ideal.

Comment: Thanks, during a port to OSX, same problem and same solution :)